# pagination personalizada con Laravel y Taillwind CSS

Tags: laravel, css3, tailwind

deseo personalizar la paginación, no quiero usar el estilo que me da por defecto esto: `{{ variable->links() }}`.
A partir de un estilo de paginación que tengo personalizado a mi gusto quiero que cuando se haga click en los botones `previous` y `next` me envíe a la página correspondiente de la tabla. ¿Como podría lograr eso?

[image: Links de navegación]

Como muestra la parte baja de la imagen, el link de arriba es el que viene por default y el de abajo es el que deseo usar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtuve la respuesta, la forma de hacerlo es agregando donde están los números de las páginas `{{ $objeto->currentPage() }}` para que muestre el número de página actual y `{{ $objeto->lastPage() }}` para que muestre el número de la última página.
Luego se agrega como referencia al botón `previous` `{{ $objeto->previousPageUrl() }}` y al botón `next` `{{ $objeto->nextPageUrl() }}`.

Para más detalles sobre cómo manejar la paginación ver `Illuminate\Pagination\LenghtAwarePaginator.php`